# how can i read a file in php where the file is located on an svn repo?

Tags: php, svn, readfile

I have a webpage that needs to be able to read a file for parsing and display content in a table. my html calls ajax calls my php, my php reads the file and parses and sends back the content for the table. I have tested this with the file on my local machine, but I need to be able to read the file when it is in svn. can someone point me in the right direction,

```
function rFile($fName)
{
    $url = "svnURL"; //my svn url
    $endName = $url.$fName.".sql";
    //echo "$endName";
    if (file_exists($endName))
    {
        //code for parsing  
    }
    else
    {
        echo " no file";

    }
```

}
this is what I am currently trying... and I always get "no file" so I know that this isnt right plus i think that I need to add credentials some how.
I am grateful for any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Accessing a SVN file directly via standard HTTP works mostly when the Apache2 webdav module is serving it. Otherwise it would need a separate svnbrowser installed, or use the cmdline client `exec("svn cat $url")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine for me:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('https://user:pass@HOST/svn/project/trunk/htdocs/index.php');
```

Given that I have the `APACHE WEBDAV` module installed on the `HOST` for svn access over HTTPS .

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the pecl extension for svn:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php

The function you probably want to use is:
svn_cat

Comment: says that svn_cat is experimental use at own risk, might that cause problems later on?